# Finite topological Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$,$Y$ be two finite topological Hausdorff spaces, how can I prove that if the two spaces have the same number of points, they must be homeomorphic?

EDIT: so sorry I missed to add the hausdorff assumption in the body, I thought it was clear from the caption.

Comment: A start: they both have, if Hausdorff, the discrete topology..

Answer (score 3):

As @David Mitra (in a comment) and @jon.sand (in an answer) have pointed out, this result is true for $T_2$ spaces. In fact, it's even true for $T_1$ spaces. For each positive integer $n$ there is exactly one $T_1$ topology (the discrete topology), up to homeomorphism, on an $n$-element set. This is because for a $T_1$ topological space each singleton set is a closed set, and since every subset of such a space is a finite union of singleton sets, it follows that every subset of such a space is a closed set, and hence every subset of such a space is an open set (i.e. the discrete topology). However, it's not true in a very strong way if we slightly weaken the separation axiom assumption to $T_0.$

A few weeks ago I happened to be looking over the paper cited below, which among other things shows how different the $T_0$ and $T_1$ separation axioms are for finite topological spaces. For example, on a $14$-element set, there are $98,484,324,257,128,207,032,183$ different $T_0$ topologies and $115,617,051,977,054,267,807,460$ different topologies. Or, to put it another way, on a $14$-element set there is exactly one $T_1$ topology and roughly $\frac{1}{6}$ [Avogadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) of $T_0$ topologies!

Marcel Erné and Kurt Stege, [*Counting finite posets and topologies*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00383446), **Order** 8 #3 (1991), 247-265.

Comment: My book has yet not gone through the notion of $T_i$ spaces. This is supposed to be a very elementary question, are you saying, as Jon.sand that this result does not hold? Because i have citet it word by word from my book.

Comment: After I wrote my answer, I saw "Hausdorff" [= $T_2$] in your title, an assumption that you did not mention in your question, so I assumed you were either trying to prove something that is not true or you simply overlooked an assumption. In trying to be diplomatic, I wrote my answer without assuming which was the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : for a point $x$ in a Hausdorff space, what is the intersection of all open sets containing it ?

If the space is finite, what property does this intersection have ?

Comment: The intersection will consist of just $x$, i dont know what property it will have if the space is finite. Anyhow I dont see at all how I can use this, I am trying to work out explicit continious functions that are inverses.

Comment: If the space is finite, that intersection is finite, and so is an open set. Therefore $\{x\}$ is open. Do you think you can go on from here ?

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not true. Consider discrete topology and anti-discrete topology. But second one is not Hausdorff.