# How many families of subsets of $[n]$ are closed under intersection and union?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $n \geq 1$. Is there a closed form, or an asymptotic estimate, for the number $g(n)$ of families $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ which are closed under union and intersection?

An obvious upper bound is $2^{2^n}$. We can furnish a lower bound by considering chains $\varnothing=S_0 \subsetneq S_1 \subsetneq S_2 \cdots \subsetneq S_m=[n]$, and the combinatorics of counting such chains do not seem too daunting, and can be solved using the [Partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: Can you calculate the answer for some small values of $n$, and then consult the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. I've done that, and it's [A306445](http://oeis.org/A306445). Indeed there's a formula.

Comment: Good. I encourage you to write up a summary of what you've found there, and post it as an answer.

Comment: You could do that today.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [A306445](http://oeis.org/A306445), the formula is given by $$g(n)=1+\sum_{d=0}^{n}\sum_{i=d}^{n} {n \choose i}{i \choose i - d}f(d)$$

where $f(d)$ is the number of topologies on a finite set of $d$ elements. Per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285831/estimates-on-number-of-topologies-on-a-finite-set), we have the estimate $\log_2 f(d) \sim d^2/4$.