# A Probability of Topology: The probability of a uniformly sampled subset of the powerset being a topology on that set

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let's say we have a finite set $S$ where $|S|=n$ and we take its powerset $X = \mathcal{P}(S)$ to generate a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{P}(X))$. From this we consider the probability space $(X, \mathcal{P}(X), \mathbb{P})$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is a [uniform probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution). **What is the probability that a uniformly sampled $A \in \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a topology on S?**

My intuition is that the probability will vanish as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but for finite sets it should be non-zero since there exists members of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ that are topologies on $S$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285831/estimates-on-number-of-topologies-on-a-finite-set says that the number of topologies on $[n]$ behaves approximately like $2^{n^2/4}$.

Comment: @NickPeterson That is very cool, and definitely applicable to the asymptotic analysis of the probability. Perhaps a useful approximation in topological data analysis, too.