# What are the number of Hausdorff topologies on the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, general-topology, permutations

**What are the number of Hausdorff topologies on the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$?**

I had once  computed the the topologies on the set $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ which comes out to be $29$.But,that was very tedious job to do.

I also tried computing the number of topoologies on $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\}$,but this seems to be more painstaking job even from before.

Now,restricting  condition of Hausdorffness on counting boggled my mind even more. I've tried a lot but every time I failed miserably.

Please suggest any elegant way so that I can classify which of the topology is Hausdorff.

Thank you

Comment: FYI, @mathematrucker posted a list of all $139$ topological spaces on a $5$ element set (no separability axioms or other assumptions) in his answer to [Is there a list of all connected T_0-spaces with 5 points?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/272751/15780).  More relevant for your question, however, is [Finite topological Hausdorff spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2504314/13130).

Answer (score 4):

A finite set $X$ with a $T_1$ topology is discrete: if all $\{x\}$ are closed, all subsets of $X$ (which are finite too) are closed too (finite unions of closed sets are closed) and so all subsets are open (every complement is also closed).

There is only *one* discrete topology on $X$, namely $\mathscr{P}(X)$. No need for counting arguments: Hausdorff implies $T_1$, of course.

Answer (score 4):

If any topology on $X$ is to be Hausdorff, for any two points $x_i \neq x_j$ there needs to be two disjoint sets, one containing $x_i$ and another containing $x_j$.

Since this has to be true for all pairs of points, each set of the form $\{x_i\}$ must be open, so by the axioms defining a topology, the power set on $X$ (the discrete topology) is the only Hausdorff topology on $X$.